# lib.d.ts Arrray.prototype.find

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

We're working on a web app that's not expect to see production for at least a year, so we're trying to be as forward thinking as possible.

We're using this [ES6 polyfill](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim) to access to things like [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). The problem is getting our Typescript code to play along.

For instance, lib.d.ts in TS 1.4 doesn't know about `Array.prototype.find`. I grabbed the Typescript source and there are a bunch of d.ts in the `bin` folder. `lib.core.es6.d.ts` and `lib.es6.d.ts` both have `find`. I tried using them in our build and the typescript compiler barfs on them ("Computed property names are not allowed in interfaces").

What would be the best approach for getting support for ES6 types in Typescript?

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to *only* copy the stuff you need. In your case just the `find` method.

```
interface Array<T> {
        /** 
      * Returns the value of the first element in the array where predicate is true, and undefined 
      * otherwise.
      * @param predicate find calls predicate once for each element of the array, in ascending 
      * order, until it finds one where predicate returns true. If such an element is found, find 
      * immediately returns that element value. Otherwise, find returns undefined.
      * @param thisArg If provided, it will be used as the this value for each invocation of 
      * predicate. If it is not provided, undefined is used instead.
      */
    find(predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: Array<T>) => boolean, thisArg?: any): T;

    /** 
      * Returns the index of the first element in the array where predicate is true, and undefined 
      * otherwise.
      * @param predicate find calls predicate once for each element of the array, in ascending 
      * order, until it finds one where predicate returns true. If such an element is found, find 
      * immediately returns that element value. Otherwise, find returns undefined.
      * @param thisArg If provided, it will be used as the this value for each invocation of 
      * predicate. If it is not provided, undefined is used instead.
      */
    findIndex(predicate: (value: T) => boolean, thisArg?: any): number;
}

var foo = [];
var bar = foo.find((x)=>true);
```

Comment: That's the conclusion I was reaching on my own. I guess the broader question is am I barking up the wrong tree? I assume other people are in a similar boat. Has someone built a polyfill package for ES6/Typescript that does this for me, with me having to maintain my own custom .d.ts file? There's a lot more than `Array.find`. For instance, the shim supports `Map<K,V>` including iterators, but the `lib.es6.d.ts` definition includes a definition of iterator that relies on computed properties.